# How do you create an email footer (signature) in Lotus Notes R5?

Tags: email, lotus-notes

For some reason I am unable to add an automated signature to new memos in Lotus Notes R5. My colleagues who have the same version as me have different options on the menu bar, including "add signature" but I do not.

Is it possible that after an upgrade from R4 a while ago I'm running in some kind of compatibility mode?

Any pointers as to where I should look? I've been trying to crack this on and off for weeks :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that you need to update your mail database template.  It's possible that your client software version is 5.x, but your mail template on the mail server is still 4.x.  You can check the template version by right clicking on the database and selecting properties.  Compare your template version to your co-workers.

In my company we have a dedicated Notes Admin that would do this.  We don't update the templates ourselves.

Hope that helps!